# For loop in python indexing string and searching string, can anyone pls explain the output

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, for-loop

```
#usr/bin/python 3.6.1
import sys

def fix_start(s):
    a = s[0]

    i=1
    for i in s:
        if a in s :
            print("found")
            s=s.replace(a,'*')
        else: print (" not found")

    return (s)

def main():
    c = fix_start(sys.argv[1])
    print (c)

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

[*`enter image description here`*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhaaC.png)

**OUTPUT:**

```
C:\Users\pavithra.sridhar\Downloads\google-python-exercises\basic>python FixString.py babble
found
not found
not found
not found
not found
not found
*a**le
```

for the command line argument 'babble',

**Expected Output**

```
Ba**le
```

replacing from the second occurrence, with * , for the rest of the occurrences.

can anyone please explain the logic why it is printing 'not found' so many times.

But desired output is : 'Ba**le' for the input Babble

Comment: Post text as text please

Comment: Hey. can you please  help me understand why i see 'found' and then 4 times 'not found' in my output. as per the code, the first letter to meet the if condition will be 'a' which does not satisfy the condition, but the first output is 'found' and then four timess 'not found'.. why is 4 times 'not found ' printed. there are only 3 letters which do not meet the condition i,,e 'a','l','e' . can you please help me understand this

Comment: You are in need of a basic python tutorial, but I'll do my best.

Comment: The output in the image does not correspond to the text in your question. Please fix.

Comment: Just get rid of the loop, keep the rest more or less intact.

Comment: @MadPhysicist: Yes, I am a beginner. Hence the struggle to understand and hence the necessity to post this question here and to understand the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python strings are *iterables*. So, your line `for i in s` will run *n* times, one for every letter in the string, and will print "not found". The first time the loop runs, it replaces `a` with`*`. So, for all subsequent runs, it will print "not found".

If I understand what you are trying to do, it would be something like

```
first_letter = s[0]
rest_string = s[1:].replace(first_letter, '*')
new_string = first_letter + rest_string
```

Comment: Let me try to understand more. So when you said, "The first time the loop runs, it replaces a with* ", do you meant the letter 'a' in the string or the string a??

and also, if you meant the letter 'a', the logic would go wrong, as the condition evaluates to true only for the letter 'b' 

and  secondly, if you meant the string a, then do you mean to say python/ the code replaces all but the first occurence of the letter 'b' in the word, in just the first iteration itself?? can you explain the flow here?? Thanks a lot

Comment: @Monsta: no, I meant the string `a`. Which, at that time, contains the first letter of the word. The `replace` replaces *all occurences* (including the first one) of the first letter. There's nothing to explain there, that's how the function is written. So, in all subsequent iterations, "not found" will be printed.

Comment: Strings are immutable. So the replacement won't affect the loop at all. What will affect it is the presence of other characters.

Comment: @blue_note : I just needed to hear this "The replace replaces all occurences (including the first one) of the first letter. "

Solves all my confusion. Thank you so much! :)

Comment: @MadPhysicist: the OP re-assigns the original string, so replacement *will* affect the loop.

Comment: @MadPhysicist: Correct. I meant the inner `if`. The actual loop, as you mention, is not affected.